# How to calculate the dimensions of the required 20 regular hexagons and 12 regular pentagons for a sphere of given diameter (the soccer ball issue)

Tags: solid-geometry

I wish to calculate the dimensions of the required 20 hexagons and 12 pentagons to tesselate a sphere of given diameter (the soccer ball issue)
I need the hexagons and pentagons to be plane figures. The sphere of a given dimension can be inscribed (all corners touching the surface, or super-scribed ( centres of all shapes touching the surface.)
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The "soccer ball" polyhedron is formally called a [truncated icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron).   According to that Wikipedia article, if the sides are of length $a$, then the circumscribing sphere has a radius of
$$
\frac{a}{2} \sqrt{ 1 + 9 \phi^2} \approx a \cdot 2.47802...
$$
where $\phi = (1 + \sqrt{5})/2$ is the golden ratio.

There's a subtlety that arises if we try to inscribe a sphere inside this polyhedron.  While the vertices are all the same distance from the origin, the centroids of the faces are not;  see Eq. (4–5) of [MathWorld's page on the truncated icosahedron.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruncatedIcosahedron.html)  Specifically, the centers of the pentagons are a distance
$$
r_5 = \frac{a}{2} \sqrt{ \frac{125+41\sqrt{5}}{10}} \approx a \cdot 2.32744...
$$
from the origin, while the centers of the hexagons are a distance
$$
r_6 = \frac{a}{2} \sqrt{ \frac{3(7 + 3\sqrt{5})}{2}} \approx a \cdot 2.26728...
$$
from the origin.  Since $r_6 < r_5$, the largest sphere that would fit inside a truncated icosahedron would only be tangent to the hexagonal faces, and would not touch the pentagonal faces.

Answer (score 1):

The soccer ball polytope is a truncated icosahedron. If you look up that term, you’ll find everything you need. For example, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) gives the coordinates of the vertices.